# Python Regex String not getting split correctly

Tags: python, regex, split

I am trying to split a line of text that looks something like this

```
host=randomhostid123 moreinfo id=otherstuffhere version="morestuff" type=TYPEA::TYPEB
```

i am tying to use split to parse it into

```
host=randomhostid123 moreinfo
id=otherstuffhere
version="morestuff"
type=TYPEA::TYPEB
```

to do this I was using

```
str.split('?[a-zA-Z]*=')
```

but all this is producing is the original string all over again
I think the regex looks ok, but I am new to python regex

Comment: split does not accept regexps... only plain strings

Comment: As a side note, it's a very bad idea to call a string `str`. That's the name of the built-in type, and the function you use to convert things to strings. For example, you won't be able to do `str(2)` to get `'2'` if you've replaced the function with a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). What you want is [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
re.split(r'\s+(?=[a-zA-Z]+=)', str)
```

This will split on spaces which are followed by words which in turn are immediately followed by `=`. Note, that you have to put everything but the spaces in a lookahead, so that it is not swallowed by the split operation.

Comment: He's using `str.split`, not `string.split`.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` in your regex is being parsed literally, and since there's no `?` in  your string it doesn't split. I think you may have been going for a regex lookahead match, but `string.split` doesn't support regexes.

---

Ah—too long looking at the documentation! m.buettner summarized things very nicely.